# Bootstrap justify-content-end not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Problem:** The `justify-content-end` class not working as expected in the `navbar` while using Bootstrap 4.

Example: I am attempting to start using css as I spend a lot of time writing custom CSS.  That said, I started trying to get a feel for it without writing any custom CSS.  I am attempting to build a `navbar` and have copied the following code over from the bootstrap docs:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light col-12">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

You will notice the `justify-content-end` class is added to the `navbar`.  When checking devtools I also see the styles being applied with that class so I know they are being applied.  However, the `nav-links` list remains on the left, like so.

[image: Local Screenshot]

However, on the docs, the same code appears like so.

[image: Docs Screenshot]

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: i guess there is no `justify-content-end`

Comment: there is though, I can see the styles being applied in the developer tools      justify-content: flex-end!important;

Comment: *However, on the docs, the same code appears like so.* .. where do you see this used on a navbar in the docs? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class needs to be applied on the parent, which is `<nav>`

**Edit:** Since there is more content inside the `nav`, the `justify-content-end` class would not work as intended. You need to use `ml-auto`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light col-12">
    <h1>H1 tag</h1>
    <ul class="nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I tried this as well but my H1 then moves to the right as well.  I know the h1 is not in the example above. I removed it from the code before pasting in here but it was right below the nav tag.

Comment: @CamGottschall Added h1 tag

Comment: Sorry, it is below the nav tag inside the nav block.

Comment: @CamGottschall Then you will not get the expected result using `justify-content-end`. Use `ml-auto` instead, edited answer

Comment: @CamGottschall And keep in mind that this fact of an extra h1 changes the original question so you must always include everything from the start. Many answers here will still cater to the info in your question currently, which doesn't serve any purpose

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to align the `nav` on the right end of the `navbar`, it would be:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

https://codeply.com/p/u2Xl8bTym0

Answer (score 1):

```
first way:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light col-12">
    <ul class="nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

second way:

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light col-12">
    <ul class="nav float-end">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsBYd.jpg
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add custom `css` for `.navbar`. `.navbar{width: 100%;}`. And remove `justify-content-end` and add `ml-auto`.

Bootstrap 4 navbar markup will like this.

```
<div class="container-fluid main-menu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        Logo
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Our Product</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:void(0);">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/MWawbBQ).

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content-end` class needs to be applied on `<nav>`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end">
    <ul class="nav ">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <a className="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">
                            Home
                        </a>

                        <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                            Link
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

You need to add **justify-content-end** in **div class="collapse"** and then add **ml-auto** in **ul**

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light col-12">
        <div class="col-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4">

        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: That works in a desktop mode but run into issues with resizing the screen and how they fold.  
Unfortunately, I feel that nothing like this should need to be added. Shouldn't it just work? I understand how naive that sounds.